# How can I change the keybinding used to autocomplete in vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, key-bindings

I'm not a big fan of `Ctrl-n`, I'd like to be able to use `Ctrl-Space`. Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: What environment? (Windows? Unix? Console vim or gvim? What terminal?)

Answer (score 36):

```
if has("gui_running")
    " C-Space seems to work under gVim on both Linux and win32
    inoremap <C-Space> <C-n>
else " no gui
  if has("unix")
    inoremap <Nul> <C-n>
  else
  " I have no idea of the name of Ctrl-Space elsewhere
  endif
endif
```

Comment: Note: you might have to use `has("gui_running")`, as `has("gui")` simply returns if your vim is compiled with `gui` option, not that you're using it right now.

Comment: It is not connected to unix directly. `<C-Space>` is translated to `<Nul>` by the terminal emulator, so if you find a terminal emulator that does the same job on windows it will work as well. And `<Nul>` is **not** a *name* of `<C-Space>` anywhere, for the same reason `<Esc>[B` is not a name of `<Down>`, it is just a symbol produced by terminal when you press `<C-Space>`.

Answer (score 21):

I like the Ctrl+Space mapping as well.

```
" Remap code completion to Ctrl+Space {{{2
inoremap <Nul> <C-x><C-o>
```

In your case you want:

```
inoremap <Nul> <C-n>
```

Comment: If you're in gvim, you'll want <C-space> instead of <Nul>.

Comment: `<C-@>` is used for C-Space in some terminals (PuTTY I think), I'm guessing <Nul> is identical to C-@

Answer (score 10):

If you wanted to map it to, say, Ctrl-E, it'd be something like:

```
inoremap <C-E> <C-N>
```

The problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> is that most terminals will just see it as a space. I'll assume you're using some terminal program inside X; if you're using something different, you'll have to supply the relevant substitutions yourself.

Bash's readline normally has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> mapped to "treat the next key as literal." So pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> then Home at a bash command line will insert `^[[H` or something like that on the command line, rather than going to the start of the line. Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>. Probably you'll just see a space.

In that case, you'll have to fool with xmodmap or write your own /usr/share/X11/xkb/* files to tell X to output something different when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>. Programs like Firefox don't care; they detect which base key is being pressed and figure out for themselves what modifiers are being pressed. But most terminal-based programs will just see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> as a Space unless you tell X to treat Space and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> differently.

I doubt you can make this change with xmodmap alone; you'll probably need to do the lower-level /usr/share/X11/xkb/* hacking. This is complicated, and I don't even know if you're using X in the first place, so I'll just leave it there.

Some terminals like urxvt let you specify your own keybindings. Like Firefox, they can tell when it's a Space and when it's a Control-Space even without you doing anything special to configure X. So you could tell urxvt to output "\033I_TYPED_CONTROL_SPACE_DAMMIT" when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>. And then you could tell vim to map *that* to `<C-N>`.

EDIT: I forgot that Ctrl-Space used to output `\0` (I remapped that somewhere else on my keyboard). In that case, all the complexity I described above is unnecessary. What I said would apply to someone who wanted to use a more exotic mapping, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-colon or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Nevertheless, it is good someone made the effort to describe whats going on here. The other answers lack any description on why their solutions work :-)